# I have 2 CommandLineRunner in same Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have 2 classes in spring boot that implement command line runner.  They basically look like this:

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 @ComponentScan("com.xxxx")
 public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {
```

and the second looks like:

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 @ComponentScan("com.xxxx")
 public class ApplicationWorklfow implements CommandLineRunner {
```

They compile fine. But when I try and run it with java -jar,  I get an error presumably as spring does not know which one to run.

is there a command that I can use that will tell the jar which application I am trying to run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have any number of `CommandLineRunner` beans but there should be only one entry point class that can have `@SpringBootApplication` annotation. Try by removing `@SpringBootApplication` annotation on `ApplicationWorklfow`.

**PS:**

It seems your main requirement is to conditionally enable one of 2 CommandLineRunner beans. You can have only one Application class and enable CLR beans conditionally either using `@Profile` or `@ConditionalOnProperty` etc.

Having multiple entry point classes with `@SpringBootApplication` annotation is not a good idea.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

}

@Component
@Profile("profile1")
public class AppInitializer1 implements CommandLineRunner {

}

@Component
@Profile("profile2")
public class AppInitializer2 implements CommandLineRunner {

}
```

Now you can activate your desired profile as follows:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=profile1 app.jar
```

With **profile1** activated, only **AppInitializer1** will run.

PS: PS:

If for some reason you still want to configure mainClass you can do as follows:

```
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>          
      <configuration>
        <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
      </configuration>

    </plugin>
```

You might leverage Maven profiles to provide different classes for different profiles. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/maven-plugin/usage.html for more info.

Comment: Then how do I tell java that I want to run ApllicationWoklfow. at that start up?

Comment: Added more info to my answer.